# PHP checkboxes that return display and return "Yes" from a database

Tags: php, checkbox, dreamweaver

I am building a site with a number of independant check boxes that collect information about industry topics.   I user will check the ones of interest and store “Yes” in the database which is Filemaker.

When they return, they will see the ones previously checked and can uncheck if needed.

To this end, I am trying to get a check box to display as checked if the database value is equal to “Yes” and display as unchecked if the value is blank.  Also, of the user checks the checkbox on the form, it will send the value of “Yes” back to the database and a value of blank if the check box is unchecked.

So far, I am only able to display the “Yes” or blank for fields.   Here is my code so far:

```
<input type="text" name="Core_Compentencies__Marketing" value="<?php echo $port_row->getField('Core_Compentencies::Marketing'); ?>"></td>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a text field, not a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

usually i use helper function to decide whether field value is checked or not.

```
<?php 
   function isChecked($value = '', $defaultVal = 'Yes')
    {
        if($value == $defaultVal)
        {
            return 'checked';
        }

    } 
    ?>

 <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Yes"  <?php echo isChecked(Core_Compentencies::Marketing); ?>>
```

Comment: I could not get this to work.  here is my code.                                                                <tr>
          <th>Core_Compentencies::Marketing</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="Core_Compentencies__Marketing" value="<?php echo $port_row->getField('Core_Compentencies::Marketing'); ?>">
        ($value = '', $defaultVal = 'Yes')
    {
        if($value == $defaultVal)
        {
            return 'checked';
        }

    } 
    ?>
  
     </td>